# Javascript: world tile generator bug? collision not working, player falls down?

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, javascript, tilemap, oop

Hi I have a serious problem here, When I generate my tile map from an array with numbers [0,4, ...] (0 > for air, 4 for solid) inside of `generateWorld()`... the collision it doesn't work, and my player falls when l walk to the left and keeps collide with that block... just keep trying until you see it, it will fall passing throught the block.

But the weird part is when l generate my world manually `generateWorld2()` my collision works very well.

This is located almost at the end of the code. Inside window.onload function

Please tell me why is that, lm not using jquery or others libraries... lm doing this game from 100% scratch. Thanks so much !

Comment: We can not help you when you don't show us any of your code. Please reduce it to the relevant parts, though. We don't want to read through your whole project.